# Limiting visibility of abstract base classes in C#

Tags: java, c#, interface, abstract, privacy

I feel like this question may be off topic as subjective, but I'm curious.

In java I'm used to using package private and public to hide the implementation of types from other packages. I usually have an `interface` such as:

```
public interface IMyClass {
    ...
}
```

Any common functionality of `IMyClass` implementations are then defined in a private `abstract class` within the same package

```
abstract class AMyClass implements IMyClass {
    public AMyClass(...)
    ...
}
```

Then the derived types are `public` and are also defined in the `IMyClass` package

```
public class CustomMyClass extends AMyClass {
    public CustomMyClass(...){
        super(...) 
        ...
}
```

---

In c# I would like to follow the same structure, but when you extend an `abstract class` it has to be `public`. The only thing I could find to prevent other packages from extending `AMyClass` or using its internal functions was to make their access level `internal`.

```
public interface IMyClass{
    ...
}
...
public class AMyClass : IMyClass {
    internal AMyClass(...)
    ...
}
...
public class CustomMyClass : AMyClass {
    public CustomMyClass(...) : base(...){
        ...
}
```

But this style still allows other c# projects 2 ways to group the subclasses, `AMyClass` or `IMyClass` types. This seems really sloppy, especially if I want to create another `abstract` base class for different types of `IMyClass`. In that case there would now be 2 abstract classes exposed that I don't want other projects to use.

Is there a way to prevent other projects from using the abstract classes, or is it simply something to put in the projects documentation and rely on an *honor system* of sorts?

Comment: I'm not getting the question. While it's true that, lacking the idea of a "package", a class in C# can't be `private`, it's not true that an `abstract` class must be `public`. You can in the same assembly inherit an `internal abstract` class with another `internal` class, implementing a `public` interface that is the only thing that's visible to the outside world. That would seem to achieve the same thing you were doing in Java, right?

Comment: @PeterDuniho If i set `AMyClass ` as `internal abstract class` I get the error  "base class AMyClass  is less accessible than class CustomMyClass"

Comment: @PeterDuniho But if I set the implementations as internal as well I guess I would have to create a factory for constructing them?

Comment: Correct. The inheritor can't be more accessible than the base class, so a factory would be required.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I way over-thought this one haha. Add this as an answer and I'll give you the checkmark ^_^

Comment: You can prevent others from inheriting from `AMyClass` by marking all the constructors as internal or private. To inherit from a class at least one constructor must be accessible to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want. Do you want to prohibit *all* use of the base `abstract` class by client code outside the assembly? Or do you simply want to prevent inheritance of it from such code?

The latter can be achieved simply by making the constructor(s) `internal`. This prevents any code outside your assembly from being able to inherit it, since they don't have access to the constructor. (Note that for non-`abstract` classes, you can also prevent direct instantiation by making constructors `protected` or `private`…obviously there's no need to do this with `abstract`, since the class can't be instantiated directly anyway).

If the former, while you are correct that C# does not have Java's concept of "package", which limits what is possible with respect to access restrictions as compared to Java, you can come close.

A derived class must not be more accessible than its base class. This means that the base class (`abstract` or otherwise) of a `public` class must itself be `public`.

But you can do much the same sort of interface-based implementation-hiding in C# as you've done in Java by making your `abstract` class `internal` (i.e. the default access for a class in C#), then a class that inherits it also `internal`, while still leaving an interface those classes implement `public`, which provides client code using the library a way to access the public features of the class.

Since making the base class `internal` prevents you from making the derived class `public`, clients of your library won't be able to create instances of the derived class directly either. So you'll have to have a public factory method in some public class which returns the public interface instead of the derived class.